# Spring Boot external configuration and xml context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to externalize my configuration with Spring Boot, but I want to continue to partially use my xml context.

My main class SpringServerApplication.java :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")})
public class SpringServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[] {
                SpringServerApplication.class, "classpath:ApplicationContextServer.xml" }, args);
    }

}
```

I put my configuration in application.properties.

And in ApplicationContextServer.xml, I want to use some parameter like this : ${user}.

But it does not work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Errors?  Exceptions?  Also at first glance I'd say, that the property source annotation is not needed, as this is the default anyway

Comment: maybe try @ImportResource instead of explicit parameter

Comment: Yes exceptions due to the fact that variables are not replaced by their value. Same error with @ImportResource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@PropertySource` as that is already done by Spring Boot, instead add `@EnableAutoConfiugration` and use `@ImportResource` to import your xml config files.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:ApplicationContextServer.xml")
public class SpringServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[] {SpringServerApplication.class}, args);
    }
}
```

That should be enough to do what you want. Depending on the content in your xml file you might even be able to drop some of it (as Spring Boot can quite easily do auto configuration of resources for you).

Comment: I just found the solution 10 mins ago... I added @EnableAutoConfiugration and it works. But thanks ! I'll also remove PropertySource.

Comment: this seems to be not working in Springboot 1.4. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<context:property-placeholder/>` in `applicationContext.xml`

And import xml based configuration like this:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

Comment: No, I have this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user' in string value "${user}"