# Disable transaction manager in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to disable transaction manager in Spring Boot application?

I have this exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined
```

Because of @Transactional annotations (I use these annotations in an other app, so I can't remove, but there is a way to ignore it? By disable transaction manager?).

Comment: Can't you just remove the spring-tx jar from the classpath (if you're not using it)?

Comment: No: ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException

Comment: Why did you need `DataAccessException`? There's not much detail to go on here. How is it possible for you to use the component with the `@Transactional` annotations without a transaction manager?

Comment: Spring boot need `DataAccessException` in `EmbeddedDatabaseConnectionSee` for example. It's because I added `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634426/spring-boot-external-configuration-and-xml-context).

Comment: I use `@Transactional` on interfaces shared by multiple projects. A project is a server, so it need transaction. An other is a client that calls server by rmi, so it use the same interface, but don't need transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have three choices:

1. remove the annotation
2. supply a transaction manager
3. exclude the configuration class that adds `@EnableTransactionManagement`

In a Spring Boot app you only get `@EnableTransactionManagement` if you are using JDBC or JPA, so really there should be a transaction manager already. The only reason I can see for one not being there is you have spring-jdbc on the classpath but no database. If you have spring-tx and spring-jdbc on your classpath already (which seems to be the case) you can just add an in-memory database (e.g. h2) to get a transaction manager. That seems like the best solution to me. But you could also exclude `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration` in your `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.