# Spring boot not honoring controllers from auto-scan directive in XML config

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have my application as such:

```
package my.package.server;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config/base.xml");
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(classPathXmlApplicationContext, DavionServer.class);
        springApplication.run();
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
package controllers;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

This is my XML file:

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="
        controllers"
    />
</beans>
```

Now, if I run the server, and I try to go to `http://localhost:8080`, I get a `404`. However, if I move `MyController` to the same package as `AppServer`, it works. According to the documentation, if I use the constructor `SpringApplication(ResourceLoader resoruceLoader, Object... sources)`, it will load all the beans from `ResourceLoader`, which in my case, is `ClassPathXMLApplicationContext`. Then why is it not honoring the `context:component-scan` directive?

This is beyond me, as I do need to use the `XML` config as well since a huge part of our project is written as XML beans and to move to a pure-annotation config just will not fit our budget.

Also, I do not understand why does spring boot need a `source` at all? My `source` is a just a dummy class with a main method, nothing else. Given a list of beans, with a bunch of `@Controller`s, why does it not just simply load them and map requests accordingly?

Almost all the examples I have seen till now are extremely simple use cases and don't go beyond a single http path. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Doing this now works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controllers"})
public class AppServer {
    ...
}
```

Why can't this directive come from the XML file?

Comment: Tell Spring Boot about your xml configuration as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634426/spring-boot-external-configuration-and-xml-context

Comment: It is only using the resource loading path NOT the application context. Also if it would be used it would be used as a parent which in turn still wouldn't work as the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` only looks for `@Controller` annotated classes in the same application context as it is defined in not the parent. Instead of hacking around just add `@ImportResource("class path:spring-config/base.xml")` to your application class.